# Como alterar a legenda de um gráfico de linhas do Primefaces?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces, chart

Estou querendo mudar o tamanho da fonte e o quadrado da legenda de um gráfico do Primefaces via JavaScript.

Meu código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alterarGrafico() {
        this.cfg.highlighter = {
            tooltipAxes : 'y'
        };

        this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
            textColor : '#000000',
            formatString : "%.0f"
        };
        this.cfg.axes.yaxis.labelOptions = {
            textColor : '#000000'
        };

        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.labelOptions = {
            textColor : '#000000'
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, apenas acrescentei o código:

```
this.cfg.legend = {               
    how : false,
    show : true,
    border : 'none',
    location : 'n',
    fontSize: '150%',
    renderer : $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer
}
```

Comment: Mas ainda não consegui aumentar o tamanho do quadrado da legenda